# Cypress - Checkbox not getting checked

Tags: checkbox, cypress

This is the checkbox element in the DOM:

[image: CheckboxDOMElement]

Here is the locator:

```js
cy.get(':nth-child(4) > :nth-child(1) > .form-group > div.col-sm-4 > :nth-child(2) > .checkbox-label > input').check({force:true})
```

The element IS being found by cypress and it believes the interaction is successful:

**Cypress successful check**

[image: CypressSuccessulCheck]

**Console check**

[image: ConsoleCheck]

However, the box is not actually getting checked from this interaction.

I have tried every combination of check/click and setting {force:true} on each of these but nothing is working.

I have also tried various alternative locator strategies and while the element is always successfully found, the checkbox is NOT getting ticked.

Has anyone else had this? This is the first time I've not been able to successfully action a checkbox and it's driving me mad.

All thoughts appreciated.

Comment: It may be listening for a click on the component containing the checkbox. Have you tried clicking on one of its parent like the label or above?

Comment: Does clicking it check/uncheck it manually?

Comment: @PeaceAndQuiet - I've tried clicking on the parent label - same result.

Comment: @DarkoRiđić - yep, manual works fine. I've implemented similar commands elsewhere in the same application which works perfectly. Which makes this doubly frustrating - feels like these checkboxes have been implemented differently to the others.

Comment: Have you tried .click() instead of .check?

Comment: @jjhelguero - yes, I mentioned that in the write up - no difference

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the event listeners on the element in devtools, for example

[image]

and try adding a `.trigger()` for each one

```js
cy.get('.checkbox-label > input')
  .check()
  .trigger('change')
```

Comment: Hi @TesterDick, thanks for your suggestion. There are no event listeners applying to this element. I tried your .trigger('change') command regardless, and unsurprisingly, the box remains unclicked/unchecked. The mystery continues but thanks again for your input...

Comment: Make sure you check ancestors as well (see checkbox above) as events can "bubble" up the HTML hierarchy.